# I have added paypal to my android app. I want to approve the payment from merchant end. How do I do this?

Tags: android, paypal

I have created an android app which uses PAYPAL. I have created a sandbox account to test the same. From customer end (individual account) the amount is deducted and it shows pending. I cannot accept the same from merchant end. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. You need to open the sandbox account and login as merchant. Payment will be auto accepted.